# Filter rows belonging to grouping factors with only one level, for applying t.test (stats R package) on a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to group by "trait_name" and "strain" and then apply a series of t.tests, with "cond" as x and "value" as y, but since the "strain" bxd8 only has ctrl in "cond" column for the glucose_0_mins trait, then I receive the "grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels" error:

```
> data

trait_name  strain  mouse   cond    value
glucose_AUC BXD1    1   ctrl    15000
glucose_AUC BXD1    2   ctrl    16000
glucose_AUC BXD1    3   treated 14601
glucose_AUC BXD1    4   treated 16781
glucose_AUC BXD7    5   ctrl    15290
glucose_AUC BXD7    6   ctrl    16000
glucose_AUC BXD7    7   treated 17654
glucose_AUC BXD7    8   treated 16523
glucose_AUC BXD8    9   ctrl    15500
glucose_AUC BXD8    10  ctrl    14200
glucose_AUC BXD8    11  treated 16541
glucose_AUC BXD8    12  treated 14532
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    13  ctrl    120
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    14  ctrl    134
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    15  treated 122
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    16  treated 111
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    17  ctrl    134
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    18  ctrl    133
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    19  treated 142
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    20  treated 134
glucose_0_mins  BXD8    21  ctrl    132
glucose_0_mins  BXD8    22  ctrl    165


> tests = data %>%
+   dplyr::group_by(trait_name, strain) %>%
+   do(tidy(t.test(.$value ~ .$cond,
+                  alternative = "two.sided",
+                  mu = 0,
+                  paired = FALSE,
+                  var.equal = FALSE,
+                  conf.level = 0.95)))

Error in t.test.formula(.$value ~ .$cond, alternative = "two.sided",  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

I would like to delete the last 2 rows.

I made this up in a way pretty similar to my table, but in my real table I have approx 10k rows with many different strains and traits, so I would like to apply a formula to get rid of any rows belonging to data that when grouping by trait and strain, the factor "cond" only contains one level (ctrl or treated), so I don't receive the error. I tried things like the following example, but didn't work, and using a combination of functions like length, unique, but still cant find a solution.

```
data1 = data[unique(dplyr::group_by(data, trait_name, strain, cond)) >1, ]
```

I really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter grouped data.frame by the number of unique `cond` values.

`dplyr::do()` is superseded, here we can use `summarise` and `dplyr::pick()` instead, `pick(cond, value)` returns a tibble containing `cond` & `value` columns for the current group; though it's only available since dplyr 1.1.0.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

df %>% 
  group_by(trait_name, strain) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(cond)) == 2) %>% 
  summarise(t_test = tidy(t.test(value ~ cond, data = pick(cond, value)))) %>% 
  unnest(t_test)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'trait_name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 12
#> # Groups:   trait_name [2]
#>   trait…¹ strain estim…² estim…³ estim…⁴ stati…⁵ p.value param…⁶ conf.…⁷ conf.…⁸
#>   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 glucos… BXD1      10.5    127     116.   1.18    0.365    1.89   -29.9    50.9
#> 2 glucos… BXD7      -4.5    134.    138   -1.12    0.461    1.03   -52.2    43.2
#> 3 glucos… BXD1    -191    15500   15691   -0.159   0.893    1.40 -8148.   7766. 
#> 4 glucos… BXD7   -1444.   15645   17088.  -2.16    0.187    1.68 -4905.   2018. 
#> 5 glucos… BXD8    -686.   14850   15536.  -0.574   0.632    1.71 -6758.   5385. 
#> # … with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>, and abbreviated
#> #   variable names ¹​trait_name, ²​estimate, ³​estimate1, ⁴​estimate2, ⁵​statistic,
#> #   ⁶​parameter, ⁷​conf.low, ⁸​conf.high
```

Example data:

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = 
"trait_name  strain  mouse   cond    value
glucose_AUC BXD1    1   ctrl    15000
glucose_AUC BXD1    2   ctrl    16000
glucose_AUC BXD1    3   treated 14601
glucose_AUC BXD1    4   treated 16781
glucose_AUC BXD7    5   ctrl    15290
glucose_AUC BXD7    6   ctrl    16000
glucose_AUC BXD7    7   treated 17654
glucose_AUC BXD7    8   treated 16523
glucose_AUC BXD8    9   ctrl    15500
glucose_AUC BXD8    10  ctrl    14200
glucose_AUC BXD8    11  treated 16541
glucose_AUC BXD8    12  treated 14532
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    13  ctrl    120
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    14  ctrl    134
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    15  treated 122
glucose_0_mins  BXD1    16  treated 111
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    17  ctrl    134
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    18  ctrl    133
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    19  treated 142
glucose_0_mins  BXD7    20  treated 134
glucose_0_mins  BXD8    21  ctrl    132
glucose_0_mins  BXD8    22  ctrl    165")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @margusl ! It worked!! I only replaced the "pick" function (it seems outdatet in cran) by "tibble" (but kept everything exactly as you put it). Thank you very much again

Comment: @Leanm, it's actually [`dplyr::pick`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pick.html), though it's quite new and is only available starting from dplyr 1.1 , published in CRAN at the end of Januray.